# Create and sign a SOAP Envelope in C# MVC 5

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I need consume a web service with WS-Security. i try building the xml file with XDocument and then sign them with a x509 certificate.

I dont know if this is the best way to do the soap envelope...

```
var XElemBody = new XElement(soapEnvNS + "Body"
, new XAttribute("Id", "Body")
, new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "wsu", wsu)
, new XElement(dgi + "WS_eFactura.EFACRECEPCIONSOBRE"
, new XElement(dgi + "Datain"
, new XElement(dgi + "xmlData"
,"<![CDATA[" + "]]>")
)
));

var soapEnv = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null)    //<?xml version="1.0"?>
, new XElement(soapEnvNS + "Envelope"
    , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "SOAP-ENV", soapEnvNS)
    , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dgi", dgi)
    , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", xsd)
    , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "SOAP-ENC", soapEnc)
    , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi)
    , new XElement(soapEnvNS + "Header",
        new XElement(wsse + "Security"
            , new XAttribute(soapEnvNS + "mustUnderstand", 1)
            , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "wsse", wsse)
            , new XElement(wsse + "BinarySecurityToken"
                , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "wsu", wsu)
                , new XAttribute("ValueType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3")
                , new XAttribute("EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary")
                , new XAttribute("Id", "SecurityToken")
                , x509Certificate // I dont know how to generate this element
            )
        )
    )
    , XElemBody
));

signSoap(keyStorePass, keyStoreName, ref soapEnv);
```

The result is very similar to that i need to do, but it not work.

Then, with the signSoap function i try to sign the xml but i ignore the correct way to do this.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
// Format the document to ignore white spaces.
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
xmlDoc = ToXmlDocument(reporte);

var x509 = new X509Certificate2(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/keyStore/") + ksName, ksPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
RSACryptoServiceProvider PrivateKeyProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509.PrivateKey;
SignedXml xmlFirmado = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

xmlFirmado.SigningKey = PrivateKeyProvider;
Reference referencia = new Reference("#Body");
xmlFirmado.AddReference(referencia);
//  <KeyInfo>           -----------------------------------------
KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
var kdata = new KeyInfoX509Data();
//  <X509Certificate>   
var xcertificate = new X509Certificate(x509);
kdata.AddCertificate(xcertificate);
//  <X509IssuerSerial>  
var xserial = new X509IssuerSerial();
xserial.IssuerName = x509.IssuerName.Name.ToString();
xserial.SerialNumber = x509.SerialNumber;
kdata.AddIssuerSerial(xserial.IssuerName, xserial.SerialNumber);
keyInfo.AddClause(kdata);
xmlFirmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

xmlFirmado.ComputeSignature();
// take a signature in a XmlElement
XmlElement firmaDigitalXML = xmlFirmado.GetXml();
var secur = xmlDoc.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild;
secur.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(firmaDigitalXML, true));
reporte = ToXDocument(xmlDoc);
```

For example i dont know how to reference the body element id with a namespace.
And i see that the id have a random characters, for example:

```
Id="Body-1v-778003-fsd3223-asxv35"
```

How is this generated?

I'm new in C#, web services and soap, any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use WCF?

Comment: thanks, i'm a noob in this, i go to researching this. I try to use wcf but i get a problem when i try to load the certificate. i will try again.